# Complicated Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a table in a database with 2 fields: index (int), email( varchar(100) )

I need to do the following:

1. Group all emails by domains names (all emails already lowercase).
2. Select all emails from all groups where the sum of emails for domain not exceeding 20% of total emails before step 1.

Code example:

```
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    //Domains to group by
    List<string> domains = new List<string>() { "gmail.com", "yahoo.com", "hotmail.com" };

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> emailGroups = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    //Init dictionary
    foreach (string thisDomain in domains)
    {
        emailGroups.Add(thisDomain, new List<string>());
    }

    //Get distinct emails
    var emails = db.Clients.Select(x => x.Email).Distinct();

    //Total emails
    int totalEmails = emails.Count();

    //One percent of total emails
    int onePercent = totalEmails / 100;

    //Run on each email
    foreach (var thisEmail in emails)
    {
        //Run on each domain
        foreach (string thisDomain in emailGroups.Keys)
        {
            //If email from this domain
            if (thisEmail.Contains(thisDomain))
            {
                //Add to dictionary
                emailGroups[thisDomain].Add(thisEmail);
            }
        }
    }

    //Will store the final result
    List<string> finalEmails = new List<string>();

    //Run on each domain
    foreach (string thisDomain in emailGroups.Keys)
    {
        //Get percent of emails in group
        int thisDomainPercents = emailGroups[thisDomain].Count / onePercent;

        //More than 20%
        if (thisDomainPercents > 20)
        {
            //Take only 20% and join to the final result
            finalEmails = finalEmails.Union(emailGroups[thisDomain].Take(20 * onePercent)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            //Join all to the final result
            finalEmails = finalEmails.Union(emailGroups[thisDomain]).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know a better way to make it?

Comment: looks like you just want to filter all the results in some way and grouping is just a steppingstone to achieve that? BTW, could you make it more clear on why `101,102` but not `100,101`, the same for `104,105` but not `103,104`? Collect items from bottom to top?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you want to completely exclude a domain if it's total count exceeds the total or if you want to include all emails up to the threshold?

Comment: I just need to take all emails till the treshold

Comment: @KonstantinFedoseev have you checked out my solution? if it doesn't work, plz leave some comment to let me know, I would like to know how it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way of doing this without hitting the DB at least twice, once for the grouping and one for the overall count, you could try something like

```
var query = from u in db.Users
            group u by u.Email.Split('@')[1] into g
            select new 
            {
                Domain = g.Key,
                Users = g.ToList()
            };

query = query.Where(x => x.Users.Count <= (db.Users.Count() * 0.2));
```

Comment: maybe by adding let userCount = db.Users.Count() * 0.2 you could do it without hitting the db twice

Comment: This will filter out the `100,101,102` while the OP wants to keep `101,102`?

Comment: @allo_man a `let` will give me the threshold but I am not quite sure how I can apply that then to the groups. KingKing I am not entirely clear on the requirement here but from what I gathered the OP wants to only return the grouping if the sum of all *domain-specific* emails is below 20% of the overall count.

Comment: Users = g.Take(userCount).ToList()

Comment: @allo_man the OP's code confirms that my question so the `let` is the way to go, will update.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to get the last items in the ascending order in each group:

```
int m = (int) (input.Count() * 0.2);
var result = input.GroupBy(x=>x.email.Split('@')[1],
                          (key,g)=>g.OrderByDescending(x=>x.index).Take(m)
                                    .OrderBy(x=>x.index))
                  .SelectMany(g=>g);//If you want to get the last result without grouping
```

Or this:

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x=>x.email.Split('@')[1],
                          (key,g)=>g.OrderBy(x=>x.index)
                                    .Skip(g.Count()-m))
                  .SelectMany(g=>g);//If you want to get the last result without grouping
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxCount = db.Users.Count() * 0.2;
var query = (from u in db.Users
        group u by u.Email.Split('@')[1] into g
        select new 
        {
            Domain = g.Key,
            Users = g.Take(maxCount).ToList()
        })
        .SelectMany(x => x.Users);
```